# Group Concat in mysql statement

Tags: mysql, select

I've got a table called `delitems` with some colums.

Within my `SELECT` statement I want to use a `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
 +-------------------------------+-------+--------+--------+-----+
 | COLOR                         | tOTAL | Ptotal | Amount | qty |
 +-------------------------------+-------+--------+--------+-----+
 | BLUE - W = 55,BLUE - W/O = 93 |   148 |    375 |  55500 |   2 |
 +-------------------------------+-------+--------+--------+-----+
 mysql>select GROUP_CONCAT(color,' = ',qty) as COLOR, SUM(qTY) AS tOTAL, suM(p_cost)  as Ptotal, SUM(qty)*SUM(p_cost) as Amount,count(*) qty from delitems where status='3' Group By cont_no;
```

Everything works fine except the `Amount` column. The total amount is wrong! Here the correct value:

```
+-----------------+-------+--------+--------+-----+
| COLOR           | tOTAL | Ptotal | Amount | qty |
+-----------------+-------+--------+--------+-----+
| BLUE - W = 55   |    55 |    125 |   6875 |   1 |
| BLUE - W/O = 93 |    93 |    250 |  23250 |   1 |
+-----------------+-------+--------+--------+-----+
mysql>select GROUP_CONCAT(color,' = ',qty) as COLOR, SUM(qTY) AS tOTAL, suM(p_cost) as Ptotal, SUM(qty)*SUM(p_cost) as Amount,count(*) qty from delitems where status='3' Group By color;
```

I only want to display it in one line with the correct total amount

Please help.

Comment: What is the problem?  Can you show us sample data?

Comment: Hi Sir!...the total amount on first query is the sum of total and Ptotal in group concat...on the second query each has its own total like BLUE -W qty is 55 * 125 and B:UE - W/O qty is 93 * 250...all I need is show the Amount total of each value in one line only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be you need sum(a*b) not sum(a)*sum(b)

```
select 
   GROUP_CONCAT(color,' = ',qty) as COLOR
 , SUM(qTY) AS tOTAL
 , suM(p_cost)  as Ptotal
 , SUM(qty*(p_cost) as Amount, count(*) qty 
from delitems 
where status='3' Group By cont_no;
```

Comment: I more problem sir...I'll post it.